# Settings dialog, using information from its parent window

Tags: c++, object-oriented, qt

My `MainWindow` popups a `SettingsDialog`. The setting dialog need to hide certain fields if the connected device is certain type.

```
void MainWindow::on_actionSettings_triggered()
{
    SettingsDialog * settings = new SettingsDialog(this);

    settings->exec();
}
```

Now in SettingsDialog:

```
SettingsDialog::SettingsDialog(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::SettingsDialog)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    QSettings settings;

    MainWindow * mainWindow = (MainWindow *) parent;

    if ( mainWindow->deviceType == DEVICE_TYPE_B )
    {
        ui->comboBoxIP->setVisible( false );
    }
}
```

It works fine but is it a good way to access the info which is present in the parent window? or should the parent window pass in the device type in the constructor so it only knows the device type and work with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the SettingsDialog can only take a MainWindow as a parent in the constructor then declare it to be so:

```
SettingsDialog::SettingsDialog(MainWindow *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::SettingsDialog)
{
```

As for getting the type indeed passing it in explicitly is better.

```
void MainWindow::on_actionSettings_triggered()
{
    SettingsDialog * settings = new SettingsDialog(this, deviceType);

    settings->exec();
}
```

My MainWindow popups a SettingsDialog. The setting dialog need to hide certain fields if the connected device is certain type.

```
void MainWindow::on_actionSettings_triggered()
{
    SettingsDialog * settings = new SettingsDialog(this);

    settings->exec();
}
```

Now in SettingsDialog:

```
SettingsDialog::SettingsDialog(MainWindow *parent, DeviceType deviceType) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::SettingsDialog)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    QSettings settings;

    if (deviceType == DEVICE_TYPE_B )
    {
        ui->comboBoxIP->setVisible( false );
    }
}
```

Comment: This does sound better than having `QWidget` pointer but still looking for a full answer which address  the two ways in my question.

Comment: Should the `deviceType`be passed by reference or pointer to make it slightly better? Also does it make sense things that we pass in constructor to be saved in member variables? I mean if they were to be used by other functions well.

Comment: @zadane I kinda assumed `DeviceType` is an enum, no need to force the compiler to pass a pointer to a 32 bit int.

Comment: Yes enum is often the case but I had this as string but I think by value is just fine. If it was more complicated structure than pointer or reference is probably a little better.

Comment: @zadane gah! stringly typed stuff,... burn it! only have string representation for showing to the user. For everything else use structure or enum.